# Where should I implement home page's HTML code?

Tags: magento2

Where should I implement home page's html code?

I should add this in the admin panel:

**content/pages/edit homepage/content** editor?

Comment: are you using luma theme or other theme ?

Comment: Hi. You want to edit which homepage section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest option would be, finding out which page is your home page.

Log in to admin panel and navigate to **Store > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Page**

Once you know which page your homepage is, open up the home page CMS page by navigating to **Content > Elements > Pages**.

*Make sure you hide the “editor” for HTML to render properly.*

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5UX4o5I   right here?

Comment: Is this the page which was in this configuration?: Store > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Page. You can chose which CMS page to display as a homepage. Also, hide the editor so you can put HTML. Unless you want to add content using the WYSIWYG ;)

Comment: Yes, this is my homepage.

Comment: Then you should be able to edit the page from there :) Let me know if you still struggle and if that solved your problem please mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: For sure and for example: https://imgur.com/a/5UX4o5I   i pasted example bootstrap code to this place, is it ok?
this code is visible on my homepage

Comment: Is the code (html) visible on the frontend? Or the output you are expecting?

Comment: the result I expect

Comment: Great! Did that solve you problem or do you have any more question in regards to this? :)

Comment: it is all, Thank You.
I have different questions in different posts

Answer (score 0):

You can put in the **content** of **CMS Pages** in admin area on **home** identifier URL, but you can deactivate editor, for that, you have a button on that area.

Or

You can use **layout** and **template** files:
In magento root path you can add `cms_index_index.xml` file in `app/design/frontend/VendorPackage/VendorTheme/Magento_Theme/layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="homepage" template="Magento_Theme::homepage.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In template file `app/design/frontend/VendorPackage/VendorTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/hompage.phtml` you can put you html code.